# Reading array from custom fields

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am saving posts by the current user's name. Furthermore, I am saving an array object - `$ganalytics_settings` - to the post in a custom field. With the following code I am trying to load the array for the username, with a specific post title:

```
    function get_custom_field_for_current_user( $customFieldName ) {

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();          
        global $wpdb;
        $id = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = '" . $current_user->user_login . "' && post_status = 'draft' && post_type = 'post' ", 'ARRAY_N');

        return get_post_meta((int)$id[0], $customFieldName);
    }
```

However, I am getting back the following object:

[image]

Instead I would like to get back the following:

[image]

Any suggestions why my function gives me back an array in array?

I appreciate your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood you, but if your function returns the array with first key being an array, then just always return that first key

```
function get_custom_field_for_current_user( $customFieldName ) {

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    global $wpdb;
    $id = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = '" . $current_user->user_login . "' && post_status = 'draft' && post_type = 'post' ", 'ARRAY_N');

    $post_meta = get_post_meta((int)$id[0], $customFieldName);

    return $post_meta[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function [`get_post_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) has the following signature `get_post_meta ( int $post_id, string $key = '', bool $single = false )`. The return value will be an array if `$single` is false. Will be value of meta data field if `$single` is true.

Try this:

```
function get_custom_field_for_current_user( $customFieldName ) {

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();          
    global $wpdb;
    $id = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = '" . $current_user->user_login . "' && post_status = 'draft' && post_type = 'post' ", 'ARRAY_N');

    return get_post_meta((int)$id[0], $customFieldName, true);
                                                      //^ Here to return single value
}
```